# CURL PHP Automatic Login

Tags: php, curl, authentication

Im trying to make an application that do a login via CURL, but i cant make this application to work, with the cookie saved after the login. Aparently i can save the cookie, but can use it. I dont know if im doing wrong in the login code or the way to use the cookie saved. This application already work if i get the cookie manually via Chrome after login. I think it generate a primary cookie after the login at this page: https://www.comprasnet.gov.br/seguro/loginPortalFornecedor.asp, that redirects to this one https://www.comprasnet.gov.br/intro.htm, generating the first cookie. After i hit the menu to this page: https://www.comprasnet.gov.br/pregao/fornec/Acompanhar.asp, it generates the two cookies needed to work.

Code i made to try to do the login:

```
<?php
$cookieold = __DIR__.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'cookieJar.txt';
$cookieactive = __DIR__.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'cookieactive.txt';
$ch = curl_init();
$url = "https://www.comprasnet.gov.br/seguro/loginPortalFornecedor.asp";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:50.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/50.0');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "perfil=Fornecedor&txtLogin=seulogin&txtSenha=suasenha&ambiente=Produção");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookieold);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);

$output = curl_exec($ch);

// Define uma nova URL para ser chamada (após o login)
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:50.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/50.0');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookieold);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.comprasnet.gov.br/intro.htm');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
// Executa a segunda requisição
$content = curl_exec ($ch);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:50.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/50.0');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookieold);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.comprasnet.gov.br/pregao/fornec/Acompanhar.asp');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookieactive);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
// Executa a terceira requisição
$content2 = curl_exec ($ch);

if ($output === FALSE) {               // verifica erros no curl
   echo "cURL Error: " . curl_error($ch);
}

curl_close($ch);
//echo $content2;
?>
```

Code that i already use with the cookie a get manually:

```
// iniciar sessao
$ch = curl_init();

// opcoes
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.comprasnet.gov.br/pregao/fornec/Acompanhar.asp");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:50.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/50.0');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, 'ASPSESSIONIDQGAADDTC=DDLGMJABKGCABIKENDGOBLJJ;ASPSESSIONIDQGCADASC=LFFGLJABPEAKKIOLNLLCOFIC');
//executar sessao
$output = curl_exec($ch);
if ($output === FALSE) {               // verifica erros no curl
   echo "cURL Error: " . curl_error($ch);
}
$output = strtr($output, $conversao); // função de conversão acentuado/não acentuado
//fechar sessao
curl_close($ch);
```

Any help will be aprecciate. Im not a programmer, just a curious guy trying to make my job easier. This application im making id for personnal use only.

Answer (score 0):

my suggestion is to `curl_close` / `curl_init` after each output line.  You are carrying over settings from the previous curl session like `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true)` and `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`

so

```
$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$ch = curl_init();

$content = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$ch = curl_init();
```

Comment: Tried that, now it saves the 2 needed cookie into file, but i cant make it use in the second piece of code. Like as if CURL dont recognize the cookie.